# How can I retrieve many values of a same field in a GET request

Tags: java, json, rest, get

I have the json to retrieve below:

```
{
  "name": "João",
  "name": "Maria",
  "name": "José"
}
```

I made this way:

```
  ResponseEntity<List<Users>> responseEntityUsers = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Users.class);
```

But I got error.

My Users class is below:

```
public class Users {

     private String name;

     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
     }
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the error you see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your JSON correctly, it is not well-formed JSON. It should be using an array of values for a specific attribute, like this:

```
{
  “names”: [“João”, “Maria”, "José"]
}
```

Notice that I have propositionally changed the attribute name to "names". Which is a good practice when designing your JSON to transport your data.
That change also will impact your Model class, that instead of String must have a String array:

```
public class Users {

     private String[] names;

     public String[] getNames() {
        return names;
     }

     public void setNames(String[] names) {
       this.names = names;
     }
}
```

I wish you the best, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your JSON for this class:

```
[
    {
    "name":"João"
    },{
    "name":"Maria"
    },{
    "name":"José"
    }
]
```